# scrape emojis with text in beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, emoji

I am trying to scrape a page using python and beautiful soup `bs4`

I want to keep the **text** in the `<p>` element in the page along with the **emojis** in this text.

The first attempt was:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urlobject = urllib.request.urlopen("https://example.com")

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlobject, "lxml")

result= list(map(lambda e: e.getText(), soup.find_all("p", {"class": "text"})))
```

But this doesn't include emojis. I then tried to remove `.getText()` and just keep :

```
result= list(map(lambda e: e, soup.find_all("p", {"class": "text"})))
```

Which made me realize the emojis in this website are in the `alt` of `img` tags:

```
<p class="text">I love the night<img alt="" class="emoji" src="etc"/><span>!</span></p>
```

So what I want to do is :

- getText() for `p` with class `text`
- But also get `alt` for `img` with `class=emoji`

**And keep the text and the emojis as one sentence.**

Is there any way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the `img.emoji` are optional you can try below, and it will preserve emoji position

```
urlobject = '''<p class="text">I love the night<img alt="" class="emoji" src="etc"/><span>!</span></p>
<p class="text">I love the day<span>!</span></p>
<p class="text">I love the music<img alt="" class="emoji" src="etc"/> <img alt="" class="emoji" src="etc"/><span>!</span></p>
'''

result = []
for p in soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'text'}):
    emoji = p.select('img.emoji')
    if emoji:
        for em in emoji:
            index = p.contents.index(em)
            p.contents[index].replace_with(em['alt'])
    result.append(p.getText())

print(result)
```

Results:

```
['I love the night!', 'I love the day!', 'I love the music !']
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following, returning tuples of the targeted data for each `p`? I just used your example `p` element twice as the input for this test:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """
<p class="text">I love the night<img alt="" class="emoji" src="etc"/><span>!</span></p>
<p class="text">I love the night<img alt="" class="emoji" src="etc"/><span>!</span></p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')

elements = soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'text'})
print(list(map(lambda e: (e.getText(), e.find('img', {'class': 'emoji'})['alt']), elements)))
```

Result:

```
[('I love the night!', ''), ('I love the night!', '')]
```

Comment: I got the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. Tried to change a bit in the code but the error persists

Comment: @HelpASisterOut Hmm, I've updated my answer with the solution in context. Can you run it successfully? Perhaps there's something peculiar about the complete data you're testing with.